# How to pass data from php to php

Tags: php, html

I want 2 pages to interact with each other. I have some data in the first page and want to pass them to the second one. Both pages are php and the data is stored in 3 variables. I saw that I can simply use the Post methode, but I dont know exactly how to use this function and it said, that this method is outdated, so what is the best way?

Comment: Where did you read that post was outdated?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **sessions** or **cookies**.
example for first page,

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['data']="your data";
?>
```

you can use this session variable to print your data in second page like this,

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['data'];
?>
```

Comment: do I have to stop or delete the session somehow, when my scripts are finished?